# Android - switching intents, app crashes unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-intent

i'm a beginner in android i was developing an app that has two screens and when i try to switch from one to another the app crashes can anybody tell me why is it happening,is that because of the declarations on the second class? i've added the second class in the manifest file and that does not seems to be the problem here.
the main class goes like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final DatabaseH dh =new DatabaseH(this);
        final EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final String[] itemsn = new String[]{"Cat","Dog","Mouse","fish"};
       final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       final TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dh.additem(ed1.getText().toString());

            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //String[] values = new String[dh.getAllContacts().size()];
                //values=dh.getAllContacts().toArray(values);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stu
                adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(dh.getAllItems());       
        //tv1.setText(dh.getAllContacts().toString());
            }});
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                //deleting the item at clicked position
                tv1.setText(listView.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
                dh.deleteContact(listView.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.addAll(dh.getAllItems());
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
        Button b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.admin);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), dbManager.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);}
                catch(Exception e){
                    tv1.setText(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:

            break;
            }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

and the second class:

```
public class dbManager extends Activity  {@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.db_manager);
    final DatabaseH dh1 = null;
    final Spinner sp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final EditText itn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemname);
    final EditText cos=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cost);
    final EditText avai=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.status);
    final RatingBar rtb1=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rating);
    Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sub);
    Button add =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Addnew);
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.addAll(dh1.getAllItems());
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dh1.addSubitem(itn.getText().toString(),cos.getText().toString(),avai.getText().toString(),sp1.getSelectedItem().toString(),rtb1.getRating());  
            }
        });
}


}
```

and this is my logcat o/p:

```
07-31 12:29:38.227: W/dalvikvm(528): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.treedb/com.example.treedb.dbManager}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.example.treedb.dbManager.onCreate(dbManager.java:30)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
07-31 12:29:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Format your question.

Comment: It is very important to understand the logs, look on this line 'at com.example.treedb.dbManager.onCreate(dbManager.java:30)', as you see everything is in log, all you need to do is to read it carefully.

Comment: Its clearly a null pointer problem so check on line 30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list1.addAll(dh1.getAllItems());`

This code line from `dbManager` Activity Class Giving you **NullPointerException**.

As you are using `dh1` object Without Initializing it. So it would be **NULL**.

Answer (score 1):

at line `list1.addAll(dh1.getAllItems());` you try tu use dh1 , but you didn't initialize it.
try this:

```
DatabaseH dh1 =new DatabaseH(this);
list1.addAll(dh1.getAllItems());
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your database helper class inside dbManager activity which throw null pointer.

Initialize it.

> dh1 = new DatabaseH(this);